# Why does disabling a submit button interfere with a form submission?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple little form that takes a number of seconds to process. I'd like to do two things:

1. Disable the submit button so the user doesn't hit it multiple times
2. Show a progress bar while the form is being processed.

I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true; 
      document.getElementById('prog').style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>

<form method="POST" action="/page" onsubmit="myFunction();">
  <input type="text" />
  <div id="prog" class="progress" style="display:none;">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 100%"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, however, I see the submit button gets disabled and the progress bar shows up but the form doesn't actually get processed. If I comment out the part that disables the submit button the form submits as normal and I see the progress bar.

Why does disabling the submit button screw up the form submission?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't do what you describe (http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q12bh4se/). Please post a complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @j08691 You can't just run it on jsfiddle since my actual form takes a few seconds to process. Also, jsfiddle won't let you redirect to "/page". That is why I didn't create a jsfiddle.

Comment: Don't give the button an ID of *submit*, it overwrites the form's *submit* method, give it some other name (doesn't fix your problem though).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could change the button type from `submit` to `button`
And, submit the form on click of the button from the javascript function

Try this code..

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true; 
      document.getElementById('prog').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    }
</script>

<form method="POST" action="/page" id="myForm">
  <input type="text" />
  <div id="prog" class="progress" style="display:none;">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 100%"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="submit" type="button" onclick="myFunction();">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: There are two serious issues with this answer: a form control with a name of "submit" masks the form's submit method, so calling `form.submit()` throws an error. Most browsers also do the same with ID, but not all. Also, the form can be submitted without clicking the button, so whatever is supposed to run when the button is clicked doesn't. The OP was unable to post code that displayed the described behaviour, this answer neither describes the issue (or the poster's guess a it) nor why it should fix it.